# Error video streaming on node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to build a simple video streaming website in node.js using socket.io but, I seem to be running into a lot of problems.

```
    module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'log'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jon2713\Desktop\sockets_folder\wcam-live\index.js:26:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

I am not sure what the problem is and I've been researching this for hours and haven't found a solution. Here is my code

Index.js

```
    var express = require("express");
var app = new express();
var http = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(http);

var Log = require('log'),
    log = new Log('debug')

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public" ));

app.get('/', function(req, res){

        res.redirect('index.html');
        });
app.listen(port,function(){
           log.info('Listening on port %s',port);
           });
```

Package.json

```
{

    "name" : "Wcam Live",
    "version" : "0.0.1",
    "dependencies" : {
        "socket.io": "*",
        "express" : "*",
        "log" : "*"
    }


}
```

Comment: `app.get('/', function(req, res)){` remove the last `)` where the error is pointing

Comment: i.e. `app.get('/', function(req, res){

        res.redirect('index.html');
        })`

Comment: Oh thank you but i still get another error D: saying "log" isnt found. I updated my question

Comment: surprisingly, you create `log` using `new Log` ... so, perhaps `Log` is broken

Comment: Did you run `npm install`?

Comment: @JaromandaX so what can i do to fix it D: and yes i installed npm

Comment: I don't know what "Log" is - node builtin?

Comment: Thats what a person was doing in a video but didn't really understand him b/c it was in spanish but that is his code word for word

Comment: Hey wasn't asking is you 'installed npm', he was asking if you ran `npm install` which installs the dependencies listed in package.json.